# How to take values of only selected checkbox in Action class in Struts 2 and JSP

Tags: java, jsp, checkbox, struts2, checked

I am displaying 24 checkboxes. I want to get all the values of checked checkboxes in action class and insert it as a new record inside database.Inserting will be done once I succeed in getting the values of checked checkboxes on button click.

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800008/how-to-retrieve-checkbox-values-in-struts-2-action-class) link in which I followed the answer answered by steven sir but with help of that I can display only boolean values but here I want text values of checkboxes selected.

So below is my JSP page.

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="eventInsertAction">
        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
          <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
          
          
          <div class="row">
            <div class="contetpanel">
                <div>
                    <div class="crevtbl"> 
                        <div class="crevtblRow"> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell">Event Name</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell2"><input name="event.eventName" class="formtextfield" type="text"><s:fielderror fieldName="event.eventName"/></div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="crevtblRow"> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell">Company Name</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell2"><input name="event.companyName" class="formtextfield" type="text" ><s:fielderror fieldName="event.companyName"/></div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="crevtblRow"> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell">Contact Person Name</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell2"><input name="event.contactPerson" class="formtextfield" type="text" ><s:fielderror fieldName="event.contactPerson"/></div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="crevtblRow"> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell">Contact</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell2"><input name="event.contactNumber" class="formtextfield" type="text" ><s:fielderror fieldName="event.contactNumber"/></div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="crevtblRow"> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell">Email</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell2"><input name="event.emailId" class="formtextfield" type="text" ><s:fielderror fieldName="event.emailId"/></div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="crevtblRow"> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell">Event Venue</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell2"><input name="event.eventVenue" class="formtextfield" type="text" ><s:fielderror fieldName="event.eventVenue"/></div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="crevtblRow"> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell">Event Date</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell2">From : <input name="event.fromDate" class="formtextfield1" type="text" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; To : <input name="event.toDate" class="formtextfield1" type="text" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD"></div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="crevtblRow"> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell">Event Time</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell2"><input name="event.eventTime" class="formtextfield1" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM  AM/PM" ><s:fielderror fieldName="event.eventTime"/></div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="crevtblRow">
                            <div class="crevtblCell">License Required</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell2">
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Rangabhoomi</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Fire NOC</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Fire Engine</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Premises &amp; NOC</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Performance</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">PWD</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Local Police</span><br />
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Collector</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">PPL</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">IPRS</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Traffic</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Liquor License</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Ticket Selling License</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">BMC Parking</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Parking</span><br />
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Port Trust</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Novex</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Foreign Artist</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">DCP Office</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Fire Marshal</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Sale Tax NOC</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Other</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Extra</span>
                            <input name="event.licenserequired" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox" value=""><span class="formcheckbox_content">Commission</span>
                                
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="crevtblRow"> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell"></div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell1"></div> 
                            <div class="crevtblCell2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Event</button></div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
            

            </section>
            </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Below is my setters and getters class**

```java
package com.ca.pojo;

public class Event {
    public Event() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private String eventName;
    private String companyName;
    private String contactPerson;
    private String contactNumber;
    private String emailId;
    private String eventVenue;
    private String fromDate;
    private String toDate;
    private String eventTime;
    private String licenserequired;
    
    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public void setEventName(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getContactPerson() {
        return contactPerson;
    }

    public void setContactPerson(String contactPerson) {
        this.contactPerson = contactPerson;
    }

    public String getContactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }

    public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getEventVenue() {
        return eventVenue;
    }

    public void setEventVenue(String eventVenue) {
        this.eventVenue = eventVenue;
    }

    public String getFromDate() {
        return fromDate;
    }

    public void setFromDate(String fromDate) {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
    }

    public String getToDate() {
        return toDate;
    }

    public void setToDate(String toDate) {
        this.toDate = toDate;
    }

    public String getEventTime() {
        return eventTime;
    }

    public void setEventTime(String eventTime) {
        this.eventTime = eventTime;
    }

    public String getLicenserequired() {
        return licenserequired;
    }

    public void setLicenserequired(String licenserequired) {
        this.licenserequired = licenserequired;
    }
    
}
```

**Below is my Action class**

```java
package com.ca.actions;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.ca.database.Database;
import com.ca.pojo.Event;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class EventInsertAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String eventId;
    Event event;
    String name;

    public EventInsertAction() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }

    public void setEventId(String eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }

    public Event getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(Event event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("Event"+event.getLicenserequired());

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hi Mahi"+name);

        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int i = 0;

        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 10000; i1++) {
            ints.add(i1);
        }
        // Collections.shuffle(ints);

        String Id = String.valueOf(ints.get(i++));

        eventId = event.getEventName() + Id;
    
        System.out.println(eventId);
        try {
            Database database = new Database();
            Connection con = database.Get_Connection();
            System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
            PreparedStatement st = con
                    .prepareStatement("insert into event(EVENT_ID,EVENT_NAME,COMPANY_NAME,CONTACT_PERSON,CONTACT_NO,EMAIL_ID,EVENT_VENUE,FROM_DATE,TO_DATE,EVENT_TIME)"
                            + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            st.setString(1, eventId);
            st.setString(2, event.getEventName());
            st.setString(3, event.getCompanyName());
            st.setString(4, event.getContactPerson());
            st.setString(5, event.getContactNumber());
            st.setString(6, event.getEmailId());
            st.setString(7, event.getEventVenue());
            st.setString(8, event.getFromDate());
            st.setString(9, event.getToDate());
            st.setString(10, event.getEventTime());
            st.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("success");
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return "success";
    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.validate();
        if (event.getEventName().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Event Name");
            addFieldError("event.eventName", "Please Enter Event Name ..");
        }
        
        if (event.getCompanyName().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("event.companyName", "Please Enter Company Name.. ");
        }
        
        if (event.getContactNumber().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("event.contactNumber",
                    "Please Enter Contact Number..");
        } else {
            String expression = "^\\+?[0-9\\-]+\\*?$";
            CharSequence inputStr = event.getContactNumber();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression,
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
            if (!matcher.matches())
                addFieldError("event.contactNumber", "Invalid Contact Number..");

        }
        
        if (event.getContactPerson().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("event.contactPerson",
                    "Please Enter Contact Person Name..");
        }
        
        if (event.getEmailId().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("event.emailId", "Please Enter Email ID..");
        } else {
            String expression = "^[\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
            CharSequence inputStr = event.getEmailId();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression,
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
            if (!matcher.matches())
                addFieldError("event.emailId", "Invalid Email Address..");
        }
        
        if (event.getEventVenue().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("event.eventVenue", "Please Enter Event Venue..");
        }
        
        if (event.getFromDate().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("event.fromDate", "Please Enter Date..");
        }
        
        if (event.getToDate().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("event.toDate", "Please Enter To Date..");
        }
        
        if (event.getEventTime().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("event.eventTime", "Please Enter Event Time..");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` attribute should not be empty  `value=""`. If you followed the linked answer you have seen that `s:checkbox` tag is used. When this tag is rendered it provided the field value for both checked and unchecked checkbox. And remarking Dave Newton's notice in his book "It should have values `true` or `false` the only viable values for the moment. These are only values that work correctly with `checkbox` interceptor."

> The 
>   
>    tag renders a single 
>   checkbox
>   . At the time of this writing it only 
>   works well with 
>   Boolean
>    (or boolean) properties. Attempting to preselect a checkbox 
>   with, for example, a string value only works if the string is 
>   true
>    or 
>   false
>   .

---

There's an example [Struts 2  checkbox example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckbox-checkbox-example/), which is using such `fieldValue` attribute.

If you want a deep incite into how `checkbox` interceptor is working you can read [`<s:checkbox>` not auto populating in struts2 form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24630857/573032).

Another example that is using multiple checkboxes [Struts 2  multiple check boxes example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckboxlist-multiple-check-boxes-example/). Unlike the `s:checkbox` it doesn't work with any unchecked values and you can map values directly using `listKey` and `listValue` attributes.

Comment: Okay first of all thankyou very much sir for your reply .Next thing is If I keep any value for my "value" attribute in my above 24 checkboxes then will I be able to get the values of only checked checkboxes ?If yes then please show me how and If I follow this link provided by you http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckbox-checkbox-example/ will I be then able to get value of multiple checkboxes in my action class ??

Comment: Should I accept yours or the below one where i have given the solution ?

Comment: How do you think which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed my datatype of variable from boolean to string[] . It will store the values of the checkbox selected. Below is my jsp.

```
<s:form action="resultAction" namespace="/">

        <h2>
            <input name="checkMe" type="checkbox"
                class="formcheckbox" value="Rangabhoomi"><span
                class="formcheckbox_content">Rangabhoomi</span> 
                <input
                name="checkMe" type="checkbox" class="formcheckbox"
                value="Fire Noc"><span class="formcheckbox_content">Fire NOC</span>

        </h2>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </s:form>
```

Below is my action class

```
package com.checkboxInStruts2;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class CheckboxAction extends ActionSupport 
{
    private String checkMe[];

    public CheckboxAction() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String[] getCheckMe() {
        return checkMe;
    }

    public void setCheckMe(String[] checkMe) {
        this.checkMe = checkMe;
    }
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i=0;i<checkMe.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(checkMe[i]);
        }

        return "success";
            }


}
```

and for display use below tag on jsp.It will display the array of string values of selected checkboxes.

```
<s:property value="checkMe"/>
```